# Get the source element of a binded function

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js to  bind certain functions from a viewmodel to html elements. One of these is a click event binded to a `<a/>` element. In the actual function, I'd like to add a classname to this element.

Please visit [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMBNh/5/) for a live example of my current situation.

What I'd like to achieve here is that the link on which the user clicks gets a red foreground color. I tried using several options, including `$(event.target).addClass('selectedlink');` as you can see in the fiddle, but without success so far. Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update `activateitem` function like this:

```
this.activateitem = function(data, context, event){
    $(event.target).addClass('selectedlink');
    this.activeitem($(data).html());
}
```